# const char* to double translation issue with C++

Tags: c++, qt, atof

I have two sample applications using the same library and the main difference between them is that one uses qt and the other application is a console application.

In the common library, I have this test code:

```
double test = 0.1;
double test2 = atof("2.13134");
double test3 = atof("1,12345");
```

The values if I use the non-qt application are:

```
test = 0.10000000000001
test2 = 2.1323399999999999998
test3 = 1   // This is the expected result using a ',' as delimitation character
```

But with the qt application:

```
test = 0.10000000000001
test2 = 2     // This is not expected!!!
test3 = 1.1234500000000000001
```

Is there any case where the behaviour of the 'atof' changes because qt?

Comment: Qt uses preprocessing of the code, which might do ungood things. Or there might be some macro at play.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This looks more like a locale issue (remember that `,` is the decimal point character in many locales) - perhaps Qt is setting a non-default locale based on system settings?

Comment: To someone from Germany, the Qt application is correct.

Comment: The main issue here is, why the decimal point character is different. Because I am not changing this intentionally, and this piece of code is not using qt at all.

Comment: @Angew: Thanks I didn't know that `atof` and `strtod` were locale-dependent. That's *horrible*. Until just a few years one *had* to set the C default user locale with g++ in Windows, because the locale support was botched.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "Qt uses preprocessing of the code, which might do ungood things." **No**, it might not. That's not how it works.

Comment: @KubaOber: "How usable is Qt without its preprocessing step?" Not very. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588154/how-usable-is-qt-without-its-preprocessing-step

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Again, that's not how it work. You claim that it "might do ungood things" is not based in any reality I'm a part of.

Comment: @KubaOber: Any preprocessing might do ungood things. That's just how it is. Learn to live with it, don't be a fanboy or bigot.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf moc doesn’t modify existing code, it generates *additional* code for signal/slots, metaobject handling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) depends on the currently set locale to tell it which character is the decimal point. In the default case ("C locale"), that is the period character '`.`'.

It's likely that Qt is setting the locale to something else. You can revert that using the [standard C[++] mechanism](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale):

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

Comment: I have included 'std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");' in the constructor of the class in the library, and it is working now. Thanks!!!

Comment: @goe: It might be a good idea to check whether narrow string literals with international characters now end up correctly as Qt strings.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are noticing is most likely caused by Qt's notion of locale. You can use:

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::C);
```

to make it work like `atof`.

**Update**

It seems `QLocale::setDefault` does not set the default locale used by Qt. It merely sets the default locale that will be created when you construct a `QLocale`. See [Changing locale in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313896/changing-locale-in-qt) and the accepted answer for more info.